# Как отключить автообновление статуса заказа в WooCommerce сразу на Processing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, order

Если выставить метод оплаты как "оплата после доставки", то новый заказ появляется сразу со статусом Processing. И клиенту отправляется письмо "Для вашего заказа получен платеж". Плюс в админке с таким статусом заказ невозможно редактировать.

Как оставить статус нового заказа Pending или сразу присвоить статус On-Hold?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Статус заказа по умолчанию устанавливается способом оплаты или шлюзом оплаты.
Можно прообывать изменять статус во время заказа, но в некоторых моментах он не будет работать. Целеcообразно изменять его после оформления(на странице спасибо) с помощью хука:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_thankyou_custom_change_order_status', 10, 1 );
function woocommerce_thankyou_custom_change_order_status( $order_id ){
    if( ! $order_id ) return;
    // Получим данные заказа
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // Если статус заказа processing изменим его на pending 
    if( $order->get_status() == 'processing' )
        $order->update_status( 'pending' );
}
```

Пример выше может работать с любыми данными заказа(их изменение) после его создания(данные получаются на `wc_get_order()`).

Comment: Такое решение работает по принципу pending - processing - pending. И письмо об успешной оплате уходит клиенту. Я использую стандартные средства Woocommerce для установления методов платежа. Может можно удалить часть кода где-то? Чтобы статус остался pending?

Comment: Кстати, если сделать pending - processing - on-hold, то письмо которое должно уходить при смене статуса на on-hold не уходит. Есть возможность отменить письмо статуса processing и отправить письмо on-hold по этому хуку?

Comment: @Андрей Я привел только пример для Вас, никто за Вас код писать не будет. Аналогично смене стетусов обычных постов, есть хуки и фильтры, которые вызываются при смене стутуса товара, так и при попытке отправки письма с изменениями. Советую почитать с примерами документацию (http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction) а также о всех хуках комерции (https://wp-kama.ru/hooks/woocommerce-hooks-db). Конкретней за емейл, список всех действий (https://wp-kama.ru/hook/woocommerce_email_actions).